# Can a MediaStream be used immediately after getUserMedia() returns?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I'm trying to capture the audio from a website user's phone, and transmit it to a remote RTCPeerConnection.

Assume that I have a function to get the local MediaStream:

```
function getLocalAudioStream(): Promise<*> {
  const devices = navigator.mediaDevices;
  if (!devices) {
    return Promise.reject(new Error('[webrtc] Audio is not supported'));
  } else {
    return devices
      .getUserMedia({
        audio: true,
        video: false,
      })
      .then(function(stream) {
        return stream;
      });
  }
}
```

The following code works fine:

```
// variable is in 'global' scope
var LOCAL_STREAM: any = null;
// At application startup: 
getLocalAudioStream().then(function(stream) {
  LOCAL_STREAM = stream;
});
...
// Later, when the peer connection has been established:
// `pc` is an RTCPeerConnection
LOCAL_STREAM.getTracks().forEach(function(track) {
        pc.addTrack(track, LOCAL_STREAM);
      });
```

However, I don't want to have to keep a MediaStream open, and I would like to 
delay fetching the stream later, so I tried this:

```
getLocalAudioStream().then(function(localStream) {
    localStream.getTracks().forEach(function(track) {
      pc.addTrack(track, localStream);
    });
});
```

This does not work (the other end does not receive the sound.)
I tried keeping the global variable around, in case of a weird scoping / garbage collection issue:

```
// variable is in 'global' scope
var LOCAL_STREAM: any = null;

 getLocalAudioStream().then(function(localStream) {
    LOCAL_STREAM = localStream;
    localStream.getTracks().forEach(function(track) {
       pc.addTrack(track, localStream);
    });
});
```

What am I missing here ?

Is there a delay to wait between the moment the getUserMedia promise is returned, and the moment it can be added to an RTCPeerConnection ? Or can I wait for a specific event ?

-- EDIT --

As @kontrollanten suggested, I made it work under Chrome by resetting my local description of the RTCPeerConnection:

```
getLocalAudioStream().then(function(localStream) {
    localStream.getTracks().forEach(function(track) {
      pc.addTrack(track, localStream);
    });

    pc
      .createOffer({
        voiceActivityDetection: false,
      })
      .then(offer => {
        return pc.setLocalDescription(offer);
      })
  });
```

However:

- it does not work on Firefox
- I must still be doing something wrong, because I can not stop when I want to hang up:

I tried stopping with:

```
  getLocalAudioStream().then(stream => {
    stream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
      track.stop();
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no such delay. As soon as you have the media returned, you can send it to the RTCPeerConnection.

In your example

```
getLocalAudioStream().then(function(localStream) {
    pc.addTrack(track, localStream);
});
```

It's unclear how `stream` is defined. Can it be that it's undefined?

Why can't you go with the following?

```
getLocalAudioStream()
  .then(function (stream) {
    stream
      .getTracks()
      .forEach(function(track) {
        pc.addTrack(track, stream);
      });
  });
```

Comment: You're right, I copy-pasted the wrong code in my question. I was actually doing what you're suggesting ; but it still does not work in my case. Any idea what I should investigate ?

Comment: Are you adding the streams to the RTCPeerConnection and then sending the new SDP with the signaler?

Comment: I've been able to make it work, but only on Chrome (see my edits)

Comment: Have you tried calling `getLocalStreams` from your RTCPeerConnection instance instead of `navigator.mediaDevices`?

Comment: When trying to get a stream ? Usually pc.getLocalStreams() does not return anything until I called addTrack. And I still don't understand why changing the localDescription of the pc makes things work on chrome but not FF...